# How to create this animation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

I would like to create one of these two animations

[https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*hQZrUD-XIU4_qsQwmOavZw.gif](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*vWK-bwwgkvThIP57s0XUwQ.gif)

or

[https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*vWK-bwwgkvThIP57s0XUwQ.gif](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*hQZrUD-XIU4_qsQwmOavZw.gif)

Are there some examples or do you have some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure, but the input animation looks really similiar to a Material Design input, my first thought is that those animations where created in Dribble or something, not an actual app, but might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `XForms.Plugin.AnimationNavigationPage` to achieve the animation when you navigate these pages.
https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage

If you want to add some animations to some controls, you could add these animation directly, such as `Translate`,`Scale`,`Rotate`,`Fade`,You can refer to this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple

There is blog that have achieve some Combined animation.
https://xamgirl.com/plug-and-play-animations-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @dalton5 Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.